# Find jobs which were preempted in SLURM

Tags: slurm

As a user (not an admin), is there any way that I can look up jobs which were preempted at some point, then requeued? I tried:

```
sacct --allusers --state=PR --starttime=2016-01-01
```

And didn't get anything, but I don't think this command should actually work, because a job which got preempted and then requeued would not ultimately end up in the preempted state.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `--duplicate` option of `sacct`; that will show you all the "intermediate states".

From the manpage:

```
   -D, --duplicates
             If Slurm job ids are reset, some job numbers will probably appear more than once in the accounting log file but refer to different jobs.  Such
             jobs can be distinguished by the "submit" time stamp in the data records.

             When  data  for  specific  jobs are requested with the --jobs option, sacct returns the most recent job with that number. This behavior can be
             overridden by specifying --duplicates, in which case all records that match the selection criteria will be returned.
```

When jobs are preempted, or requeued, you end up with several records in the database for the job, and this option allows you to see all of them.

Comment: So then, if the result of the command `sacct --allusers --state=PREEMPTED --starttime=2016-01-01 --duplicates` is empty, this means there have not been any jobs preempted on this cluster at any point this year?